# How to change excel wrong number format with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to import and process some `csv` files which are exported from excel.
Is there any way to change a wrong format of date applied to a cell that should have a number format, using python with pandas?

As shown in the attached image,
"7/25/1965" is equivalent to 23,948.00
"11/10/1933" is equivalent to 12,368.00
etc.

[image]

Comment: Can't you fix it in Excel?

Comment: Yes, I can fix it in excel, but I want to automate the process

Comment: In Excel, click on the column header and change type to numeric or currency.

Comment: In the worst case scenario I would have to output an error message to the user asking for the correct column format

Comment: If you read them in with `pandas` then it will the file from the xml node, meaning it should be in its raw format not what Excel deems it should be, Pandas should be able to either natively handle this or use the `pd.to_datetime` method to cast it into your desired format. That said, provide some data and your expected output as _text_ not an image. Did you attempt to read this in pandas yet? what issue have you had so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the number of a given date correspond to the number of days since 1/1/1900. So you could in python count the number of days between those two dates using `datetime.date` object.

For example : `date(2020, 7, 11) - date(2020, 7, 2) = 9`

Then you replace the date value by the number you just calculated.

That said I believe it is still better to fix the problem at the source rather than in python as suggested in the comments

Comment: This worked, but it is missing 2 days from the result. For example `pd.to_datetime('10/3/1930') - pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900')` equals `11232`, instead of `11234`. Any ideas why?